# Problem installing RATT

Tags: software-installation, sequence-annotation, functional-annotation, ratt

I have followed the steps [here](http://ratt.sourceforge.net/) to install RATT, i.e.:

```
svn co "https://svn.code.sf.net/p/ratt/code/" ratt-code
```

However, when I check my installation by running '$RATT_HOME/start.ratt.sh', it says:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /start.ratt.sh
```

which makes sense once I check that the RATT_HOME variable is empty.

I downloaded their tuberculosis example, went into that directory and ran:

```
~/path/to/my/ratt/ratt-code/start.ratt.sh embl F11.fasta F11 SimStrain
```

and got the following output:

```
Please set the RATT_HOME variable.
At Sanger for bash it is RATT_HOME=/nfs/users/nfs_t/tdo/Bin/ratt; export RATT_HOME
At Sanger for tcsh setenv RATT_HOME /nfs/users/nfs_t/tdo/Bin/
```

What should I set my RATT_HOME variable to? The message only says what it should be set to at the Sanger Institute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the home of a program is where the executable is. In order to make the system aware you need to include it as a variable when the terminal is run.

So you need to add it to the file at `~/.bashrc` of your computer (if you are using bash as shell [you can check it with `echo $SHELL`]). You need to add :

```
export RATT_HOME=path/where/RATT/is/installed/or/downloaded
```

As terdon says in a comment below:

> Note that echo `$SHELL` just prints the default login shell of the
>   user, and not necessarily the shell that is currently running.  Also,
>   `~/.bashrc` is not read by macOS bash which starts login shells by
>   default. In any case, this sort of global variable should be in
>   `~/.profile`, not `.bashrc`. For more of this sort of detail see
>   [Sequence of scripts sourced upon login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login/463479#463479) and [How to correctly add
>   a path to PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path/26059#26059).